# Cannot update document by index in FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

I'm attempting to update a document using an index in my FaunaDB collection using FQL.

```
Update(
  Match(
    Index('users_by_id'),
    'user-1'
  ),
  {
    data: {
      name: 'John'
    }
  }
)
```

This query gives me the following error:

```json
Error: [
  {
    "position": [
      "update"
    ],
    "code": "invalid argument",
    "description": "Ref expected, Set provided."
  }
]
```

How can I update the document using the index `users_by_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Match` returns a set reference, not a document reference, because there could be zero or more matching documents.

If you are certain that there is a single document that matches, you can use `Get`. When you call `Get` with a set reference (instead of a document reference), the first item of the set is retrieved. Since `Update` requires a document reference, you can then use `Select` to retrieve the fetched document's reference.

For example:

```
Update(
  Select(
    "ref",
    Get(Match(Index('users_by_id'), 'user-1'))
  ),
  {
    data: {
      name: 'John'
    }
  }
)
```

If you have more than one match, you should use `Paginate` to "realize" the set into an array of matching documents, and then `Map` over the array to perform a bulk update:

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Match(Index('users_by_id'), 'user-1')
  ),
  Lambda(
    "ref",
    Update(
      Var("ref"),
      {
        data: {
          name: "John",
        }
      }
    )
  )
)
```

Note: For this to work, your index has to have an empty `values` definition, or it must explicitly define the `ref` field as the one and only value. If your index returns multiple fields, the `Lambda` function has to be updated to accept the same number of parameters as are defined in your index's `values` definition.

Comment: I haven't got time to test your answer but I'm sure it works lol, thank you!